# uninstalling Office 2007 with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, uninstallation

I'm trying to write a script which uninstalls Microsoft Office 2007 Enterprise by grabbing the IdentifyingNumber using Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product.  I'm able to grab the IdentifyingNumber, but when I attempt to uninstall PowerShell outputs some information that I'm not sure what to do with.  Is this not a proper way to utilize Uninstall()?

```
$2k7 = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object { $_.IdentifyingNumber -match "{90120000-0030-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}" } 

if ($2k7 -ne $null) {
  $2k7.Uninstall()
}
else {
  write-host "nothing to see here"
}
```

Output...

```
__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : __PARAMETERS
__SUPERCLASS     : 
__DYNASTY        : __PARAMETERS
__RELPATH        : 
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 1
__DERIVATION     : {}
__SERVER         : 
__NAMESPACE      : 
__PATH           : 
ReturnValue      : 1603
```

Comment: 1603 means a fatal error occured. You should be able to use `.Uninstall`. I wonder if there is another reason why it is not working. What happends if you try to `msiexec.exe /x {90120000-0030-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE} /quiet` in the same script? I would imagine you are having another issue that is not the scripts fault.

Comment: previously when I've tried calling msiexec /x it would popup the msiexec help box indicating that there was an issue with the /x or /uninstall flag.  Doing it now however seems to work.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Error 1603 is a catch-all error used by Microsoft Installer when an unexpected failure is encountered.

I would verify that you're running your Powershell window with elevated privileges and that the program you intend to uninstall doesn't have any processes currently running.